# What's a good way to use MongoDB Atlas in Firebase functions?

Tags: mongodb, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm using MongoDB Atlas connected in Firebase functions.
Currently I am using it in the following way.

```js
const functions = require("firebase-functions")
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb')
const uri = "mongodb+srv://-----"
const mongodb = new MongoClient(uri)

exports.myfunc = functions.https.onCall( () => {
  return mongodb.connect().then(()=>{
    const collection = mongodb.db("db_name").collection("col_name")

    return collection
      .find({/* query */}).toArray()
      .finally(() => mongodb.close() )
  })
})
```

Is it a good way to `connect` and `close` to mongodb every time I call `myfunc`?

I am concerned that this method is putting unnecessary load on the server.

I tried to find a better way, but I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

Its a good practice close the connection, to close the resources after they are used and before exiting the application. The MongoClient#close() method API documentation says:

> Close the client, which will close all underlying cached resources,
> including, for example, sockets and background monitoring threads.

Closing the connection before exiting the application.

[click here](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/software-development/mongodb/mongodb-close-isclosed-example/) more documentation.